# Linux awk with condition

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have a very large file (2.5M record) with 2 columns seperated by |.
I would like to filter all record that do not contain the value "-1" inside the second column and write it into a new file.

I tried to use:

```
grep -v "-1" norm_cats_21_07_assignments.psv > norm_cats_21_07_assignments.psv
```

but noo luck.

Comment: Hint: `awk -F"|" '{print $2}` returns the second column..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this through awk,

```
awk -F"|" '$2~/^-1$/{next}1' file > newfile
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat r
foo|-1
foo|bar
$ awk -F"|" '$2~/^-1$/{next}1' r
foo|bar
```

Comment: `/-1/` will also hit `-10` `-12123` etc, you need `$2~/^-1$/` or `$2=="-1"`

Answer (score 1):

For quick and dirty solution, you can simply add `|` to your grep:

```
grep -v "|-1" input.psv > output.psv
```

This assumes that rows to be ignored look like

```
something|-1
```

Note that if you ever need to use `grep -v "-1"`, you have to add `--` after options, otherwise grep will treat `-1` as an option, something like this:

```
grep -v -- "-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have:

```
awk -F'|' '$2 != "-1"' file.psv > new_file.psv
```

Or

```
awk -F'|' '$2 !~ /-1/' file.psv > new_file.psv
```

- `!=` matches the whole column while `!~` needs only a part of it.

Edit: Just noticed that your input file and output file are the same. You can't do that as the output file which is the same file would get truncated even before `awk` starts reading it.

With `awk` after making the new filtered file (e.g. `new_file.psv`), you can save it back by using `cat new_file.psv > file.psv` or `mv new_file.psv file.psv`.

But somehow if you exactly have 2 columns separated with `|` and no spaces in between, and no quotes around, etc. You can just use inline editing with `sed`:

```
sed -i '/|-1/d' file.psv
```

Or perhaps something equivalent to `awk -F'|' '$2 !~ /-1/'`:

```
sed -i '/|.*-1/d' file.psv
```

Comment: I tried          awk -F"|" '$2!="-1"' norm_cats_21_07.psv > norm_cats_21_07_assignments.psv           but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @user3628777 Can you show some lines from your file? Also, make sure your file is in UNIX format: `sed -i 's|\r||' your_file`

Comment: my mistake - the seperator was wrong. after correcting the seperator from "|" to " " it worked